# Array expand with one formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

input:

```
A 4
B 3
C 2
```

output:

```
A
A
A
A
B
B
B
C
C
```

Using only one formula. no code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A:A&CHAR(9);B:B));CHAR(9)))))`

Comment: look likes the `REPT()` has a 100 limit

Comment: That's correct, unfortunately. You can nest the REPT functions, such that something like this will cover up to 10,000 repetitions: `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(REPT(A:A&CHAR(9);INT(B:B/100));100)&REPT(A:A&CHAR(9);MOD(B:B;100)));CHAR(9)))))`

Comment: Adam, I have a problem with the `Concatenate` function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368544/new-google-spreadsheet-concatenate-limit-50000-characters-use-array-literal So I thought back to your answer here and how `REPT()` can be nested. Is there a way to nest `CONCATENATE()` also to get around the 50000 character limit?