# New Google spreadsheet Concatenate limit 50000 characters

Tags: google-sheets

Migrating to new Google spreadsheets. I have a custom formula that combines a few arrays into one array

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE('Monthly link'!A10:A&CHAR(13) , 'Monthly link'!R10:R&CHAR(13) , 'Monthly link'!AG10:AG&CHAR(13) , 'Monthly link'!AU10:AU&CHAR(13) )), CHAR(13)))`

this formula works perfectly fine in the old Google spreadsheet, but in the new one, it gave me a "`Error: Text result of CONCATENATE is longer than the limit of 50000 characters.`"

Is there a way around this? I've tried the `Array_Literal` formula but can't seem to get it to work, that seems like the a possible solution. But it seems the function combines arrays across and not down.

I've tried:

`=array_literal('Monthly link'!A10:A,'Monthly link'!R10:R,'Monthly link'!AG10:AG,'Monthly link'!AU10:AU)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking back to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897310/google-spreadsheet-array-expand-with-one-formula-no-code-pls), you can probably nest concatenate:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(CONCATENATE('Monthly link'!A10:A&CHAR(13) , 
'Monthly link'!R10:R&CHAR(13)), CONCATENATE('Monthly link'!AG10:AG&CHAR(13) ,
'Monthly link'!AU10:AU&CHAR(13)) )), CHAR(13)))
```

I simply added in one more `CONCATENATE` to combine the strings with only one value, then use `CONCAT` to combine those.

**EDIT**

This isn't exactly a fix, but reading [google documentation](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3541068?hl=en&ref_topic=20322) states that you can create an old spreadsheet by going [here](https://g.co/oldsheets).

**EDIT 2**

Try this code:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCAT(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE('Monthly link'!A10:A&CHAR(13), 
'Monthly link'!R10:R&CHAR(13))), ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(
'Monthly link'!AG10:AG&CHAR(13), 'Monthly link'!AU10:AU&CHAR(13)))), CHAR(13)))
```

It seems the error is coming from `ARRAYFORMULA`, has it has a limit of 50000. Not `CONCATENATE` or `CONCAT`. So, I use `CONCAT` to combine two different `ARRAYFORMULA`s that both house half of the original data. You can continue to divide these until there are even 4 `ARRAYFORMULA`s that all only have one dataset if need be.

**EDIT 3**

Currently, I am working on implementing a function in javascript found [here](https://gist.github.com/liammcinroy/9906910).

You can test it currently by `Tools->Script editor->Paste`, then to run it go `Tools->Script Manager->organizeData->Run`.

I'll continue to work on it... it is currently not working, but I am close;)

**EDIT 4**

I finished it! You can see it [here](https://gist.github.com/liammcinroy/9924666). You need to create a new script using the above instructions (`Tools->Script editor->Paste`), save it, then you can run it from the Script Editor window or from the spreadsheet by doing `Tools->Script Manager->organizeData->Run`.

What the script does is gets the data from the forms, puts it in the data to be copied, then it has a strange restriction where it requires a letter in the column to be able to copy it,  so it adds a letter in so the script will fill the rows with "undefined". From there, all of the rows have "undefined" in them, so data can be copied to all of them.

If you want to know how to implement the script directly into a cell, you can just put:

```
=organizeData()
```

it will call the custom function! See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions) for more details.

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately it didn't work. `Error: Text result of CONCAT is longer than the limit of 50000 characters.`

Comment: @jason_can't_code Hmmmm... Can you use two different cells?

Comment: can you elaborate? I guess i could, but it wouldn't be dynamic. How would I know where to start the second cell?

Comment: @jason_can't_code Good point... I'm going to check the documentation on these functions... I think one might automatically insert newlines so you then effectively increase your char count by a lot

Comment: Yeah, this function basically a work around for joining many databases   into one since there is no `JOIN()` function in the `QUERY` function. It's ghetto but it works.

Comment: @jason_cant_code Unfortunately, I cannot test the new google sheets... However, check my edits as you can still create old sheets, and also how many data values total are you using?

Comment: @jason_cant_code I think I have a solution. Check edits

Comment: I have just over 50000 characters i think because it used to work. Then it stoppped. That means it grew to be over 50k. Btw, edit 2 had some errors `Error: Wrong number of arguments to SPLIT. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 1 arguments.` I can't go back to the old spreadsheets anymore. Too slow.

Comment: `Error: Text result of CONCAT is longer than the limit of 50000 characters.` I was hopeful, because spreadsheet computed for quite a while (like 10 seconds), but at the end... still same problem.

Comment: @jason_cant_code Check my edits... Ill continue working an update it later

Comment: ok cool. I'm going to give you the bounty regardless. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @jason_cant_code I've solved it! Check my edits for all the info

Comment: wow. +200 lines of code? going to take a while for me to absorb it, but the bounty is yours.

Comment: @jason_cant_code Haha... Most of it is google's, from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)... The only part you really need to worry about is the `organizeData()` function.

Answer (score 11):

Don't know if this is working, but might be worth a shot. Someone posted this on Google Docs help forum.

```
/.../ If you want more than 50,000 characters in a single cell, you can use QUERY's header clause.

Example:

=ArrayFormula(query(row(A1:A70000),,100000))

This creates a cell with 408,893 characters. You can verify by using the LEN function.
```

Ok I fixed the above line like this, I think it works:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(A1:A100000,,100000))
```

This is provided that you have data in column A, from row 1 to row 100000. It will concatenate all of it. I guess max length is 100000 characters?

Comment: Thanks, this trick worked like a charm for me.
I've tried to test the length limit and it worked for 4 035 566 characters. Might be more as I stopped testing at that point.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is related to another similar Q, marked as duplicete:

[Text result of JOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471043/text-result-of-join-is-longer-than-the-limit-of-50000-characters)

My solution is to use the formula:

`=query(joinSplit(A2:A, ";"), "select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1", 0)`

where `joinSplit(A2:A, ";")` is a custom formula.

The code to paste into script editor is:

```
function joinSplit(column, delim)
{
  var result = [];
  var row = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = column.length; i < l; i++)
  {
    row = column[i].join(delim).split(delim);
    row.forEach( function(elt) { result.push([elt]); } ); 
  }  
  return result;
}
```

It will return the column of unique items.

If data is:

```
A;B;C;D
D;D
E;F;A;A
G;A;B;C
```

The result is column:

```
A
B
C
D
D
D
E
F
A
A
G
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 0):

The joinSplit script SAVED MY LIFE.

I tweaked it to trim out whitespace in case your data has a ", " in it.

```
function joinSplit(column, delim)
{
  var result = [];
  var row = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = column.length; i < l; i++)
  {
    row = column[i].join(delim).split(delim);
    row.forEach( function(elt) { result.push([elt.trim()]); } ); 
  }  
  return result;
}
```