# Q: Transpose -> Merge(?) on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to transpose data such that rows transpose into a single column stacking on top of each other.

[image]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({TRANSPOSE(A1:C1);TRANSPOSE(A2:C2);TRANSPOSE(A3:C3)})
```

This formula essentially does what I want but what if I have many more rows? Would I need to enter; `TRANSPOSE(Col(x):Col(y))` for every single row?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",1,A:C),","))`

[image]

Notes:

- `textjoin` will join text and skip blanks. Add spaces in column C to have an empty row.
- limit of join function is [50000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368544/new-google-spreadsheet-concatenate-limit-50000-characters)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Is there a way to get around the 50000 character limit?

Comment: Your welcome! The limit is known issue, please see answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368544/new-google-spreadsheet-concatenate-limit-50000-characters

Answer (score 1):

Max Makhrov's answer is good, but indeed subject to the 50k limit. To get around that, I have recently found another method which is explained in my 
[interlacing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48669572/34704) to another question

In your case this would look something like this (up to arbitrary 9 rows):

```
=query(
   sort(
     {arrayformula({row(A1:A9)*3, A1:A9});
      arrayformula({row(B1:B9)*3+1, B1:B9});
      arrayformula({row(C1:C9)*3+2, C1:C9})}
   ),
   "select Col2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something, or why does nobody suggest [`Flatten`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en)?

```
FLATTEN(A1:C3)
```

And you can use `Filter` as usual to filter out blank cells, e.g.

```
=FILTER(FLATTEN(A1:C3);FLATTEN(A1:C3)<>"")
```

Comment: Question was asked in 2018. There was no flatten function then. It's only recently announced like late 2020.