# REPT is throwing a "Text result of REPT is longer than the limit of 32000 characters." error - alternativce function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, repeat, array-formulas

I'm trying to repeat a set comma separated values twice, leading this set to exceed the limit of 32000 characters that `REPT` allows.

Is there any way to use an alternative for this such as javascript or using the query functionality?

I've already tried building a Google script function replicating this but that threw an internal custom javascript error that could not be resolved.

This is the function:
`=REPT(JOIN(",",ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(SPLIT("1010,1020,1050,1051,1052,1060,1070,1080,1081,1090,1091,1092,1093,1094,1100,1120,1150,1180,1200,1240,1250,1260,1280,1290,1300,1301,1310,1312,1320,1321,1323,1330,1331,1342,1345,1350,1355,1360,1380,1390",",")&",",19))),40)`

This is the error:

> Text result of REPT is longer than the limit of 32000 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little late for this answer, but if anybody else needs it, you can do a recurrency of *player0*'s answer, and by combining it with a simple google script, create dynamic, parametrizable and large `=REPT()`.

Taking your initial string, let's name it *text1*

```
    text1 = "1010,1020,1050,1051,1052,1060,1070,1080,1081,1090,1091,1092,1093,1094,1100,1120,1150,1180,1200,1240,1250,1260,1280,1290,1300,1301,1310,1312,1320,1321,1323,1330,1331,1342,1345,1350,1355,1360,1380,1390"
```

Calculate it's length. A simple way would be doing `=LEN(text1)`. In this case, the length would be 199 characters. The `=REPT()` character limit is 32000, so for *text1* the maximum amount of times you can repeat it is `32000/199 = 160.804`. We will hold this value rounded down as:

```
    max_repts = ROUNDDOWN(32000/199) = 160
```

Now, having this, let's define the total amount of repetitions you need to do as `XLargeNumber`. With this and the `max_repts`, we can see the total of times we'll need to repeat the `=REPT()` statement by doing:

```
    amount_repts = ROUNDUP(XLargeNumber / max_repts)
```

The `ROUNDUP` here gives us the total amount of repts, but we still need to take into account that the last one will not probably be with the `max_repts`, but it will be less, so we also need:

```
    last_rept_amount = XLargeNumber - (max_repts*(amount_repts-1))
```

With this, we are going to dynamically generate the formula by making use of the `{}` [array constructor](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) from google sheets, and appending the `=REPT()` one aside each other, as well as using the `ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(range,,large_number))` technique than we can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368544/new-google-spreadsheet-concatenate-limit-50000-characters) like this:

`"=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY("{"&REPT("REPT(text1,max_repts)"&IF(amount_repts-1>1,",",""),amount_repts-1)&IF(amount_reps-1>0,IF(amount_reps-1=1,",","REPT(text1, last_rept_amount)"),"")&"}"),,(LEN(text1)*amount_repts)))"`

This will give us the formula as a text, so to pass it you can either copy and paste values, or instead, use a custom google script to introduce it in the cell you'd like. The script could look like this:

```js
function set_formula() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Yourspreadsheet');
  var target = ss.getSheetByName('TargetSpreadsheet');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  // 0 index row and column where the text formula is
  var formula = data[row][column];
  
  // Set formula
  target.getRange(start_row, start_col, num_rows, num_cols).setFormula([[formula]]);
  
}
```

Having this, you can generate a dynamic formula, and introduce it as needed. You can even automate it more by adding triggers, and attaching to moving data.

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure you really know that you need it

your formula is too big but if you change **`40`** to **`8`** it will work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(JOIN(",", REPT(SPLIT(
 "1010,1020,1050,1051,1052,1060,1070,1080,1081,1090,1091,1092,1093,1094,1100,
  1120,1150,1180,1200,1240,1250,1260,1280,1290,1300,1301,1310,1312,1320,1321,
  1323,1330,1331,1342,1345,1350,1355,1360,1380,1390", ",")&",", 19)), 8))
```

so now you just need to stack it in VR array 5 times:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({REPT(JOIN(",", REPT(SPLIT(
 "1010,1020,1050,1051,1052,1060,1070,1080,1081,1090,1091,1092,1093,1094,1100,
  1120,1150,1180,1200,1240,1250,1260,1280,1290,1300,1301,1310,1312,1320,1321,
  1323,1330,1331,1342,1345,1350,1355,1360,1380,1390", ",")&",", 19)), 8);
 REPT(JOIN(",", REPT(SPLIT(
 "1010,1020,1050,1051,1052,1060,1070,1080,1081,1090,1091,1092,1093,1094,1100,
  1120,1150,1180,1200,1240,1250,1260,1280,1290,1300,1301,1310,1312,1320,1321,
  1323,1330,1331,1342,1345,1350,1355,1360,1380,1390", ",")&",", 19)), 8);
 REPT(JOIN(",", REPT(SPLIT(
 "1010,1020,1050,1051,1052,1060,1070,1080,1081,1090,1091,1092,1093,1094,1100,
  1120,1150,1180,1200,1240,1250,1260,1280,1290,1300,1301,1310,1312,1320,1321,
  1323,1330,1331,1342,1345,1350,1355,1360,1380,1390", ",")&",", 19)), 8);
 REPT(JOIN(",", REPT(SPLIT(
 "1010,1020,1050,1051,1052,1060,1070,1080,1081,1090,1091,1092,1093,1094,1100,
  1120,1150,1180,1200,1240,1250,1260,1280,1290,1300,1301,1310,1312,1320,1321,
  1323,1330,1331,1342,1345,1350,1355,1360,1380,1390", ",")&",", 19)), 8);
 REPT(JOIN(",", REPT(SPLIT(
 "1010,1020,1050,1051,1052,1060,1070,1080,1081,1090,1091,1092,1093,1094,1100,
  1120,1150,1180,1200,1240,1250,1260,1280,1290,1300,1301,1310,1312,1320,1321,
  1323,1330,1331,1342,1345,1350,1355,1360,1380,1390", ",")&",", 19)), 8)},,999^99))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

`SPLIT` converts the text into numbers and `REPT` works only on text.

So consider reversing the sequence;

- Repeat the string
- Then split it

`=split(rept("1010,1020,1050,1051,1052,1060,1070,1080,1081,1090,1091,1092,1093,1094,1100,1120,1150,1180,1200,1240,1250,1260,1280,1290,1300,1301,1310,1312,1320,1321,1323,1330,1331,1342,1345,1350,1355,1360,1380,1390,",2),",",true,true)`

Comment: I'm only repeating it twice, not 600 times