# How to avoid the TEXTJOIN character limit with large Google sheets for matching values?

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I've got four different sheets on one Google Sheet file. What they are is meter usage and costs from two different companies. The meters are the same, but when switching to the other company, they made a new ID. However, the usage and cost stayed the same. I'm trying to find a way to look at the two different sheets to match up the usage and costs on both sheets, and have it return the ID on the new company. If I can find a way for it to return the ID of the old one as well to use as a key when we're trying to convert everything over manually, that would be awesome.

Currently working formula:

```
=QUERY('Copy of BillHistory'!1:9916,"SELECT A,B,E WHERE D MATCHES
  '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'Copy of Add Bills-Water'!D:D)&"' AND C MATCHES
  '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'Copy of Add Bills-Water'!C:C)&"' AND D > 0", 1)
```

What I want but doesn't work:

```
=QUERY('Copy of Add Bills-Water'!1:1000,"SELECT A,B,E WHERE D MATCHES
  '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'Copy of BillHistory'!D:D)&"' AND C MATCHES
  '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'Copy of BillHistory'!C:C)&"' AND D > 0",1)
```

However I get

> Text result of TEXTJOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters.

Sheet copy:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ds2-CiVtUXBs07FzRsMvbUZjK2w8p7FJY0DbN-oFrlc/edit?usp=sharing

Edit: Fixed the TEXTJOIN length issue by making it only view 1000 rows at a time, but it now only shows the headers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please provide small sanples of the two tables in question, preferably as text - you should also add a link to a full sample if it suits to reproduce the issue, but not as image

Comment: see also here for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368544/new-google-spreadsheet-concatenate-limit-50000-characters

Comment: I added a copy of the sheet I'm working with. Those solutions didn't seem to work for me, but maybe I'm not smart enough to use them, lol.